# Unable to access MySQL database in browser

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am accessing a database remotely. I can access the database through the terminal with user name and password but in the browser, it gives the following error message.

`Cannot log in to the MySQL server
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Output of the command `select user, host from mysql.user order by user;`

```
| user             | host       |
+------------------+------------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost  |
| mysql.session    | localhost  |
| mysql.sys        | localhost  |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost  |
| root             | localhost  |
| root             | Ipaddress of remote system |
| root             | %          |
+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Has the user `phpmyadmin` the right to access MySQL from `localhost`? It also [depends on the protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/938794/cannot-login-to-mysql-from-localhost-with-host-set-to), I guess phpMyAdmin uses TCP, unlike the `mysql` command. Also please _always_ include error messages as text in your questions, see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals, http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: By accessing the server through ssh I can able to login `mysql -u phpmyadmin -p root123` With the same username and password when i try to access ipaddress/phpmyadmin/ it throws the error which I have mentioned above.

Comment: This supports my hypothesis about having different privileges for different protocols. Please [edit] your question to add the output for the `select user, host from mysql.user order by user;` query. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text. And also add the error message as text, as I requested earlier.

Comment: I have edited the question with the ouput you have asked for.

Comment: Sorry. Now i have added the error message in text.